# Failover cluster connection issue

Tags: clustering, failover

I'm trying to run SQL Server Failover cluster in Azure.

I have **NODE1** and **NODE2** in a cluster and another **SERVER** in the same network trying to connect to the database server using the instance from the cluster.

- **NODE1** can connect to cluster instance when **NODE1** is the active node.
- **NODE2** can connect to cluster instance when **NODE2** is the active node.
- **SERVER** can connect to cluster instance if using **NODE1** network name and **NODE1** is the active node.
- **SERVER** can connect to cluster instance if using **NODE2** network name and **NODE2** is the active node.

1434 udp and 1433 tcp are on in both nodes. SQL Browser is running, Portqry 1434 returns the SQL instances only if I use the nodes network name but not the cluster network name.

I've googled and tried everything you can imagine (disabled firewall, changed network card loop flags, used different ports, add endpoints in azure for a variety range of ports, etc...)

To make it short... I want to know if there's some sort of restriction in Azure that doesn't allow me to make this work.

Comment: I know nothing about this, but it sounds like a VIP address fails over to the active node